# jax-ws import and customizing package to namespace mapping

Tags: java, jax-ws

How do I customize the packages of the namespaces when using jax-ws to generate the java artifacts.

I'm running jax-ws iwsmport via maven.

I don't want to change the default package, I want to be able to map from more than one namespace to different packages.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<jaxb:bindings 
            schemaLocation="../../wscontract/src/main/resources/wsdl/address.xsd"
    node="//xsd:schema[@targetNamespace='http://demo.iae.ws/address']">
    <jaxb:schemaBindings>
        <jaxb:package name="demo.ws.address" />
        <jaxb:nameXmlTransform>
            <jaxb:typeName prefix="Customer" />
        </jaxb:nameXmlTransform>
    </jaxb:schemaBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Use [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/) bindings with the wsimport `-b` switch. You can find some sample files [here](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2011/04/java-jax-ws-web-services-and-clients.html#ws_bindings).

Comment: and then I can reference multiple of these binding files?

Comment: @Michael Wiles - you can pass more than one binding file with multiple `-b` switches. It should also possible to [add JAXB instructions to your schemas](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html#wp148975) if you prefer that approach.

Comment: and you can also include multiple of these jaxb:bindings in the one bindings file as well as far as I can tell

Comment: @Michael Wiles - yes, you can bind any number of schemas from one binding file.