# Changing package for generated classes in CXF

Tags: java, namespaces, package, cxf

The question is whether it is possible to assign different packages for different namespaces for cfx to generate.

I have a wsdl generated by .Net application. Now I need to use it in java app. By default it generates several packages. Like `com.microsoft.schemas_2003._10.serialization`, `datacontract.schemas._2004._07` ....  And the package with the name of the target namespace.

If I add `-p` parameter and set package, than all the classes are placed in thin one package.

Is it somehow possible to change only one package and leave others as they are? Exactly I don't want this package with targetNamespace name, want to change it.

Comment: The answer was already given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214576).

Answer (score 1):

As dma_k mentioned, the standard jaxb/jaxws binding files is the standard way to do it.

You can do it with the -p flag as well though.  The -p flag allows a namespace -> package mapping:

```
-p <[wsdl-namespace =]package-name>*
```