# wsimport throws package related error while parsing wsdl to java

Tags: java, wsdl, wsimport

I am trying to parse a WSDL using wsimport. I have jdk 1.6.
I searched for related issues on SOF and on web and found that the error I get:  `The package name 'interface.whateverpackage.imports' used for this schema is not a valid package name` is due to the java key words present in the targetNameSpace for schema.
But couldn't find any fix for this. Can anyone guide me how to fix this issue?

Comment: You should be able to map certain namespaces to custom package names with custom bindings. See this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6214830/1028345

Comment: I think that it is not related to this issue though.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below mentioned format to create client.
in cmd.
`D:\temp>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin\wsimport.exe"` - keep http://localhost:9999/service.wsdl

This will create all the wsdl classes in D:\temp directory after that create jar and you are ready to go.